# SQL Server Management Studio 2016: The application cannot start

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, ssms

I installed SQL Server Management Studio 2016. When I tried to open it gives this error. I tried uninstall and again install. Also I uninstall all Visual Studio and SQL Server and reinstall all of them but problem still continue.
How can I solve this issue?

[image]

Comment: If nobody knows the answer straight away, you might be able to find the source of the problem using [Process Monitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645). It's not always easy though...

Comment: make sure you are using the correct version (32 bit or 64 bit) for your Windows OS. You can open the windows event viewer and see exception details (eventvwr)

Comment: I checked. SSMS and my pc is 64 bit. Not a version problem

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In my case, the issue was with broken VS2015 isolated shell installation.

I resolved it by downloading and re-installing this shell from Visual Studio Isolated Shell page https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ca/visualstudio/extensibility/visual-studio-isolated-shell (which should eventually lead you to http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=615451 - after filling out the survey).

Note:

1. I had following warnings after the VS1205 shell install. But that
   did not matter, since the existing version of these components was
   higher.
2. I had no VS IDEs installed on my computer prior to
   installing SSMS 16.5.3 (or 17.1). Both had the same issue. For now I
   am using only SSMS 16.5.3, since I do not have a need for 17.1

[image: VS 2015 Shell installed warnings]
[image: Current VS 2015 installed components]

Answer (score 1):

I completely remove all microsoft application and re install sql server 2016 and the reinstall ssms and ssms worked and finally I install vs17 now its working.
Problem is about to "Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 Shell(Isolated)"

We need to install vs after ssms.

Answer (score 1):

Happened to me on SSMS v17.9.1.
I've repaired Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 Shell (Isolated) and the problem went away.

Answer (score 0):

According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ect3fzs0.aspx) documentaion:-

> An unexpected error has prevented Visual Studio from starting. This error appears when one of the following items occurs:
>
> - The integrated development environment (IDE) was not able to load Msxml3.dll.
> - The IDE was not able to load Mso.dll.
> - The IDE was not able to load DTE.olb.
> - The license key for Visual Studio was not created during setup.
> - Script blocking is turned on and not allowing scripting code to execute.
> - Setup for the .NET Framework, a component required by Visual Studio, failed to generate a valid native image for mscorlib.dll.
> - The Klez virus is present on your computer

And the article is introduced specific procedures to correct this error.

Hope helps.