# Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 17: The application cannot start

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, ssms-2017

After reinstalling the Visual Studio Professional 2017, since then 
I used to get the error message as **The application cannot start**, while opening the Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 17

I had repaired and reinstalled but still the problem exist.

[image]

Is there any way to work around to fix this issue?

---

**Referred:**

- [SQL Server Management Studio 2016: The application cannot start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43833408/sql-server-management-studio-2016-the-application-cannot-start/44703693)
- [SQL Server Management Studio 2012 Application Cannot Start](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/126000/sql-server-management-studio-2012-application-cannot-start)
- [SSMS : How to fix SQL Server Management Studio not opening problem](https://www.howtosolutions.net/2019/05/fixing-microsoft-sql-server-management-studio-ssms-not-loading-problem/)
- [SSMS 17.8.1 error on startup: 'The application cannot
  start'](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/Lync/en-US/4f974144-ab51-49a3-9755-440e3693f06d/ssms-1781-error-on-startup-the-application-cannot-start?forum=sqltools)

Comment: Any additional errors in the Windows application log?

Comment: Checked, since there were no errors noticed. Tell all the relevant commands to look in depth @JacobH

Comment: Maybe there is something useful in the [SQL Server setup logs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/install-windows/view-and-read-sql-server-setup-log-files?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: In `SQLServer_ERRORLOG_2019-10-31T17.17.08.log` last message says Recovery is complete. This is an informational message only. No user action is required. I couldn't find any errors over there @JacobH

Comment: Tried installing the latest version of SSMS instead?

Comment: Yes!,
Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio - 17.6
File Version: 14.0.17230.0

@Larnu